# Getting all selects with the same selected value in Prototype $$()?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dollar-sign

How get all select with the same "selected value" in Prototype $$()?

**Example: all select with "5" select value**

```
<select name="first">
  <option value="">-- Selecione --</option>
  <option value="4">Auxiliar de vistoria</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="5">Examinador</option>
</select>

<select name="second">
  <option value="">-- Selecione --</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="4">Auxiliar de vistoria</option>
  <option value="5">Examinador</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: The more effort you put into your question, the more and better quality answers you get. Can you make what you're asking more clear? Maybe give an example or two? By "select" do you literally mean `select` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$$('select:has(option:selected[value=5])')
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/a5t4a/